# Issue with iOS table view custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm having a problem with my `UITableView` custom cell.

This is the UITableView code:

```
var contactName = ["Papa", "Mummy", "Ajay", "Deepak", "My"]
var phoneNumber = ["657464567", "354636346", "5436346", "6345634643", "5645634656"]

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contactName.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
    cell.name.text = contactName[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

And this is my custom cell code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
```

I double checked that everything is connected properly so please help me figure out why I'm having this problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, can you post that error

Comment: error is not showing just it showing empty table in device or simulator

Comment: Did you set datasource for the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You have used UITableViewController so you need to return number of sections as 1. So change the code like below :

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
```

To

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: i've removed that function so it default is 1 and i do write like this alway by the way i also tried this is (above one which you suggested)  i don't this is an issue here

Comment: Then did you get any crash in the log. Please post that